# Parameterisation of faces of a tetrahedron.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, parametrization

I have to parameterise the faces of the tetrahedron, $z = 0$, $y=0$, $x=y$, $x+z=1$ and use their normal vectors to find the surface integral $\int_Sxy\ dS$. I'm not sure if I have parameterised correctly and especially unsure about the surface integral.

My attempt: 
$z = 0:$ 
$x\mathbf{e_1} + y\mathbf{e_2}$
Normal vector: $
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
$y = 0:$ 
$x\mathbf{e_1} + z\mathbf{e_3}$
Normal vector: $
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
$x = y:$ 
$y\mathbf{e_1} + y\mathbf{e_2} + z\mathbf{e_3}$
Normal vector: $
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
$x + z = 1:$ 
$x\mathbf{e_1} + y\mathbf{e_2} + (1-x)\mathbf{e_3}$
Normal vector: $
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Then my method was to integrate over each face at a time and add them together but using the parameterisation so they were all double integrals and using the modulus of the normal vectors as the change of variables bit.
Eg:
For $z = 0$:
$\int_0^1\int_0^1xy\ dx\ dy = ... = \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: You integrated over a square for the case $z=0$, but the face of the tetrahedron is a triangle.

Comment: A few comments/questions: 1. The normal vectors don't directly enter into scalar surface integrals. Did the problem statement mention finding normal vectors? 2. Did the problem statement explicitly require you to calculate four integrals by parametrizing, or only to "calculate the integral directly" or something similar? Some of the face contributions vanish because the integrand is identically $0$ on a face. 3. Are you happy with setting up limits of integration over triangular plane regions?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes, the question was in three parts, the first was a sketch, the second was to parameterise and find normal vectors and the last part is the integral. I've done double integrals with triangles with like x-simple and y-simple graphs, I can try that.

Comment: Sorry just to clarify my above comment, the second part was to parameterise each face and find normal vectors in each case, the third part asking for the surface integral didn't say anything about doing different parts I just wasn't sure how to do it.

Comment: Some of your vextors are inward pointing, while others are outward pointing. Fortunately for you, this integration is not oriented, but in general, you should choose all your normal vectors to point outward.